# How to test AJAX with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, tdd

Can somebody give advice, how to test AJAX in Ruby on Rails?
For example: i click to button, query going to TestController#new, and in that method we have respond_with(@test) and new.js.erb, where is html form. Ok, i can click_to this link/button, xhr query will work, but i don't get any responses, which i need to test.

Can some body help with this, please?
I'm using Rspec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Capybara and Selenium. Look at [this great Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara).

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 4.2 , for send ajax request, set optional hash argument with key "xhr: true" to call of get, post, patch, put, or delete method.
For example:

```
get users_path + '?page=2', xhr: true
```

and then use assert_select for verify some HTML elements on updated page.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your Ajax request has .. it may actually be best to test it on multiple levels.

Test your controller's response with a controller test.

Test your JS correctly dealing with this response with a pure JS testing framework like jasmine.

Test your flow through the application with something like cucumber, or an integration rspec (with the help of capybara/selenium).